# Get items in a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

This is my array:

```
$keyArr = array(12345 => array("somto@gmail.com", "james@yahoo.com",), 54321 => array("munz@gmail.com",));
```

Here's my statement:

```
foreach ($keyArr as $dbkey => $dbvalue){
  if (!in_array($email, $dbvalue) && $dbkey != $key || in_array($email, $dbvalue) && $dbkey != $key || !in_array($email, $dbvalue) && $dbkey == $key){
    $errors['key'] = "Invalid email or key!";
  }
}
```

Say I create a variable that exists in $keyArr such as:

```
$key = 12345;
$email = "somto@gmail.com";
```

I expect no output from the program, because the values of $key and $email exist in $keyArr, but I still get the "Invalid email or key!" message.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you simply want to determine if the value in $email exists in the list referenced by $key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got an associative array, you can actually do this without a loop:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $keyArr) || !in_array($email, $keyArr[$key])) {
    $errors['key'] = "Invalid email or key!";
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/QtTe0).

Comment: Perfect! I'll also try to get around using a loop, to aid my learning process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those values do not match *every* record so it will always display that error. You need to only set that error after you have looped through every item in the array and haven't found a match.

```
$error = true;
foreach ($keyArr as $dbkey => $emailAddresses){
  if ($dbkey === $key && in_array($email, $emailAddresses)) {
    // MATCH! Break out of the loop before we can set the error message
    $error = false;    
    break; 
  }
}
if ($error) {
    $errors['key'] = "Invalid email or key!";
}
```